# Writing .dsv file in dynamic folders in U-SQL script

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am new to U-SQL and am trying to read multiple .dsv files from a folder and write the output as .dsv files in dynamic folder/sub folder. So far I have successfully read multiple .dsv files and am able to write the files in a single location(pre-defined location) but am not able to write the .dsv files into multiple folders/subfolders. The folders and subfolders are defined based on the file name. As an example,
If the file name is ABC_20200421@015814.dsv, it should be reading data from the .dsv file and write it into folder system: test/ABC/2020/04/21/File_Data.dsv

The code I have so far is :

```
DECLARE @ImportFile string = "*.dsv"; -- To read all the .dsv files and move them to folder locations 
DECLARE  @Code String = @ImportFile.Substring(0, 3); 
DECLARE  @CommanName String = @ImportFile.Substring(4, 14); File_Contents
DECLARE  @Year String = @ImportFile.Substring(18, 4); 
DECLARE  @Month String = @ImportFile.Substring(22, 2); 
DECLARE  @File_Date String = @ImportFile.Substring(24, 2); 

 @result=
SELECT col1,col2,col3 
FROM Table1

//Writing to dsv file:

OUTPUT @result
TO "test/"+@Code+"/"+@Year+"/"+@Month+"/"+@File_Date+"/File_Data.dsv"
USING Outputters.Text(delimiter : '|', quoting: false);
```

On running the code, I get an error:

E_CSC_USER_EXPRESSIONNOTCONSTANTFOLDABLE: Expression cannot be constant folded.

Details:

at token '"/test/"', near the ###:

OUTPUT @result
TO  ###
"/test/"+@Code+"/"+@Year+"/"+@Month+"/"+@File_Date+"/STAY_REVENUES.dsv"
USING Outputters.Text(delimiter : '|',  quoting : false)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which service you are using to run the U-SQL script?

Comment: I am using data lake analytics gen 1

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of OUTPUT statement.

U-SQL’s OUTPUT statement writes the specified rowset to the provided file path URI. **A file path URI has to be provided as a static string expression (an expression that can be constant folded) in the `TO` clause of an `OUTPUT` expression.**

**Try this:** As you are using `@result` in SELECT statement, the same should be used in `OUTPUT` statement as mentioned in this [official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/concepts/files/output-to-files).

```
OUTPUT @result
TO "test/"+@Code+"/"+@Year+"/"+@Month+"/"+@File_Date+"/File_Data.CSV"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader: false, quoting: false);
```

Comment: I probably had typo in the code here. the script that I was running has the dataset for select and output expression.